# Index Out of Range Exception Using Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I am using a Task.FromAsync and Task.ContinueWith method to complete my work. I am using a List in my program and when I run it, it gives me an Index Out of Range Exception. However, when I go through the debugger it runs through and finishes just fine. Is there something that I am missing or does Tasks operate differently when using them with a loop and a List?

```
public int TimerCounter = 0;
public IList<WebsiteResult>webResult = new List<WebsiteResult>();

public void sendRequest(){
    foreach(Website web in TempVar._allWebsites)
    {
        webResult.Add(new WebSiteResult {});
        try
        {
        pageCheck(web);
        webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).RequestSentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if(webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus == null)
            webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus = "";

        TimeCounter++;
    }
}



public void pageCheck(){
    IAsyncResult asyncResult;
    Uri uri = new Uri(TempURL); //TempUrl is assigned a string beforehand
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    try{
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            myReq.BeginGetResponse,
            asyncResult => myReq.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
            (Object)null);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result;
                ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result);
                if(responseCode.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
                  webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).ResponseStatusCode = "Up"; //Error occurs here
                  reponseCode.Close();
                }
            }
        );
}
//catch exceptions
}

private String ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response) {
    StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string str = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: can you show your code.. debugger tends to have different results in regards to how things are run in release mode

Comment: @DJKRAZE It should be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your call to `pageCheck()` sets up a continuation that will be run when the `Task` finishes/completes. However, the call to the `pageCheck()` method will return to the caller (`sendRequest()`) almost immediately after setting up and spinning off your `Task`. Your `Task` will take time to execute on a background thread pool thread, but will return control to `sendRequest()` quickly which then tries to access your `IList` which will have no elements as these are populated in the continuation. This *may* work *sometimes* depending on how the `Task` is dispatched by the Thread-Pool optimiser and how long the task takes. If you step through using the debugger this can effect the way the `Task` is fired and can effect the order of operation - so again *can* effect the outcome of these operations.

My advice would be to put your

```
task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result;
        ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result);
        if(responseCode.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).ResponseStatusCode = "Up"; //Error occurs here
            reponseCode.Close();
        }

        webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).RequestSentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if(webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus == null)
            webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus = "";
        TimeCounter++;
     });
```

into the continuation inside `pageCheck()`. The other option is to create another method which wraps this process in a 'higher-level task', to you would set up your `Task` and the continuation in the `sendRequest()` method instead.

*Note, using a lock in this case will not helps you as you cannot tell when the lock will be imposed. It will likely not effect the order of execution and your problem will remain.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: I took that block of code and put it within the other method but it did not work. I also initialized the List with 15 entries(web urls), I ran it again and the same error came up but TimerCounter = 15(Out of bounds) and the List was on its 15th entry(Last element).

Comment: After TimeCounter is incremented to 15 it should stop right there and jump out of the loop. I will try the other option you stated.

Comment: What are you doing using a timer this way (unless I have miss-understood). This does not sound right either. Yes, `TimeCounter = 15` _will_ be out-of-bounds as `Lists` are ZERO BASED! This means to access the 15th element you use `myList[14]`.

Comment: Yes so for the code.
    foreach(Website web in TempVar._allWebsites)
    {
        webResult.Add(new WebSiteResult {});
        try
        {
        pageCheck(web);
        webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).RequestSentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        if(webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus == null)
            webResult.ElementAt(TimerCounter).SystemStatus = "";

        TimeCounter++;
    }
}
After the loop goes through the 15th element in the list the TimeCounter is still incremented to 15 but for some reason it may be going back through giving it the exception

Comment: Please see edit. Of course the `TimeCounter++;` should have also been in the continuation. I have edited the code above...

Comment: does the same thing apply if I wanted to print out the results of each url? Would I have to call the Console.WriteLine inside of the ContineWith? Currently I am printing the results after everything is completed and some things goes missing but when I am debugging everything runs as it should.

Comment: I am printing everything after the for each loop in the SendRequest method.

Comment: You will need to print in the continuation for the same reason I outlined in the answer: to preserve/ensure the correct order of operation...